# PHP IP Restriction from array

Tags: php

**(1.)** I want allow visitors to access a page just from a some IP Address Range *(paragraph 2)*. easily as adding more regex of IP Address to IP Address List.

**My regular expression array is :**

```
$IP_LIST_ACCESS = array(  
"/^188\.133\.11\.([1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1([0-9][0-9])|2([0-4][0-9]|5[0-4]))$/"  
,"/^188\.133\.14\.([1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1([0-1][0-9]|2[0-8]))$/"  
,"/^127\.0\.0\.1$/"                                                         
);
```

**(2.)** IP Range of above array is `188.133.11.1-188.133.11.254` and `188.136.14.1-188.136.14.128` and `127.0.0.1`

and bellow is **My codes to detect wrong ip address and die:**

```
$USER_IP_ADDR = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
foreach ($IP_LIST_ACCESS as $IP_ACC_ARRAY)
{
  if (!preg_match($IP_ACC_ARRAY, $USER_IP_ADDR))
  {
    echo '#INVALID IP'; #DEBUG
    die;
  }
}
```

**(3.)** with my above codes , always give `INVALID IP` Error (always detect as wrong IP address) .
**Where is the problem ?**

**EDIT**
**(4.)** I just want to do this , not exact with preg_match if have a better way .

Comment: Better convert the IP to a number and check if it is in a given range. After all, an IP address is just a 32 bit unsigned integer.

Comment: You are heading for a nightmare - maintaining code with a hard coded list of IP addresses. Suppose somebody uses DHCP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Better use ip2long insted of regex, its easyer to read and has better performance.

```php
$ip_ranges = array(
    array(
        'from' => ip2long('188.133.11.1'),
        'to' => ip2long('188.133.11.254')
    ),
    array(
        'from' => ip2long('188.136.14.1'),
        'to' => ip2long('188.136.14.128')
    ),
    array(
        'from' => ip2long('127.0.0.0'),
        'to' => ip2long('127.255.255.255')
    ),
);

$USER_IP_ADDR = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$USER_IP_ADDR_LONG = ip2long($USER_IP_ADDR);

$USER_IS_PERMITTED = false;
foreach ($ip_ranges as $ip_range) {
    if ($ip_range['from'] <= $USER_IP_ADDR_LONG && $ip_range['to'] >= $USER_IP_ADDR_LONG) {
        $USER_IS_PERMITTED = true;
    }
}


if (!$USER_IS_PERMITTED) {
    echo '#INVALID IP: ' . $USER_IP_ADDR; #DEBUG
    die;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but give always too `INVALID IP` , where is the problem ? can test it ?

Comment: sorry have had written the same wrong logic like you. now it works.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [`ip2long()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ip2long.php), it generates an IPv4 Internet network address from its Internet standard format (dotted string) representation.

Later, you can perform range operations on it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly certain you want `if (preg_match($IP_ACC_ARRAY, $USER_IP_ADDR) === 1)`. Right now you're displaying the error if it *doesn't* match. This is the quickest solution, but perhaps the `ip2long`-based solutions proposed in other answers is the most correct.